# Oracle APEX 5 charts not working as expected

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I've created a chart in Oracle APEX 5 with 3 different data series:

Series 1: Line
Series 2: Bar
Series 3: Line

I've enabled multiple y-axis with different scales.

When I create Series 1, it uses primary y-axis automatically (as expected).
When I add Series 2, it uses extra y-axis automatically (as expected).
When I add Series 3, all three series start using the primary y-axis (unexpected).

I want Series 1 and 3 to use the primary y-axis and Series 2 to use the extra y-axis. I had created similar chart before and it worked fine. This time I'm unable to get Series 2 to use the secondary y-axis, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hilary's sample application, the 2nd series should be the one used for the extra y-axis. 
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=36648:7

You may get a response from the APEX dev team if you ask in the OTN forums, especially if you provide a sample on apex.oracle.com